# Setting an attribute to launch configuration in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, attributes, launch

An application in eclispe3.7, I want to set an attribute to the launch configuration on each launch. Iam using the following command for setting the attribute, But when getting the attribte, it shows only the default attribute value only.

```
launch.getLaunchConfiguration().getWorkingCopy().setAttribute(IGDBLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PORT, value);
```

On another class, launch from the first class is getting by using the following code:

```
launch.getLaunchConfiguration()..getWorkingCopy().getAttributes();
```

Why the attribute cannot be set? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you are getting different working copies with each call to getWorkingCopy().  If you check the Java ID of the working copy object in the debugger then you will be able to tell for sure.

Hope this helps,
 Thomas

Answer (score 0):

When you use getWorkingCopy(), you get copy of original state, but you need use doSave() besides.

```
ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy launchCopy = launch.getWorkingCopy();
launchCopy.setAttribute(IGDBLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PORT, value);
launch = launchCopy.doSave();
```

You can read, how does it work here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.platform.debug.devel/240